# If $X$ is first-countable then a net converges when a subsequence converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, examples-counterexamples, nets, first-countable

Let be $X$ and we assume that $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is a net such that there exists a cofinal and increasing map $\varphi$ form $\Bbb N$ to $\Lambda$ such that $\big(x_{\varphi(n)}\big)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to any $x_0\in X$: so if $X$ is first countable then the convergence of $\big(x_{\varphi(n)}\big)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ to $x_0$ implies the convergence of $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ to $x_0$? If the answer to the last question is negative then there is a relevant reason different form [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739354/if-x-and-y-are-first-countable-then-lim-x-to-x-0fx-y-0-iff-lim-n-t) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385527/proof-for-sequentially-continuous-function-with-a-first-countable-domain-is-cont)  or rather [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822063/the-relation-between-first-countable-and-closure) that show why into first countable space is sufficent to consider only sequence?

Comment: A usual convergent subsequence of a non convergent sequence provides a counter example to your question.

Comment: @Ruy Okay, so there are no other reasons other than the ones I listed for considering sequences instead of nets?

Comment: Yes, these are the main reasons.  In a 1st countable compact space every sequence has a converging subsequence but unfortunately the converse is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ruy suggested above into the comments the conjecture is generally false: e.g. the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ defined as
$$
x_n:=\begin{cases}0,\,\text{if }n\,\text{is even}\\n,\,\text{if }n\,\text{is even}\end{cases}
$$
is a sequence into a first countable space that does not converege but it has trivially a converging subsequence.